# Android Apps: Recieving data from secure location

Tags: java, android

I am new to app development on android, and I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve information from any secured website, of course by sending a correct username and password.
The user would enter his user name and password in the app, and the app would enter the website, log in automatically, retrieve data from a page, showing it in the app (all of this behind the scenes).
This is a general question, and it would be very helpful to know where to begin and what is needed in general for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you mean reaching https endpoints, yes you can.
I'll take a look to the [Apache Http Library](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html) in Android.

There's also a nice tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html) if you start from the beginning.